# Flex: Filter XMLListCollection even if test node doesn't exist

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, filter

I want to show some data from an xml file inside a datagrid, so I do this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dgDomains" dataProvider="{new XMLListCollection(xmlDomains..domain(deleted.toString() != '1'))}"
...
```

and the xml data looks like this:

```
  <domains>
    <domain>
      <domainName>AGRICULTURE</domainName>
      <deleted>1</deleted>
    </domain>
    <domain>
      <domainName>IT</domainName>
      <deleted/>
    </domain>
  </domains>
```

The filter fails if the "deleted" node isn't there. I get this error: Variable deleted is not defined.

Can someone help me improve the filter so that it will work in this case, too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fails with error because filter can't apply's on null/undefined variables in your case **delete**,
you may uses XML's **elements** function it will take care of null/undefined value

```
xmlDomain..domain.(elements('deleted') != '1')
```

*above statement also return's all nodes in which delete is not defined*

Hopes that helps